# Arnova 10 G2 won't start

Tags: boot

I recently got a Arnova 10 G2 in my workplace for testing. But unfortunately this device doesn't start up at all. I have charged it now for more than half a day. The Green led glows while I connect the charger. And sometimes I can see a home screen showing "ARNOVA" and that's it. It goes off. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the culprit is the faulty hardware. Send it back for replacement or repair, if it's still on the warranty. There's nothing you can do yourself.